Getting ERROR: XX000: Materialized view could not be created on redshift
I encountered an error while trying to recreate a view with the same name after dropping the current one:

SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Materialized view could not be created.

Interestingly, if I change the view's name and run the SQL query, it gets created successfully.
Underlying DDL is same for creating MV.

We had the same error today and after searching for 4 hours we found it :
In dbeaver going to the "Fonctions" file there was a PROCEDURE for the old materialized view. " BEGIN IF Recompute_MV THEN EXECUTE ...."
Deleting the procedure solved the problem.
This procedure doesn't appear in the dependancies.
Hope it can help you if you still have the problem
